# Remover parâmetro da URL com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou criando uma funcionalidade para um sistema e me deparei com a necessidade de manipular parâmetros da URL, desta forma, gostaria de saber, como excluir um determinado parâmetro da URL?

Segue um exemplo mais claro:

```
http://site.com.br?c=cliente&a=editar&id=31228
```

Eu preciso remover o parâmetro `a=editar` da URL, tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var urlReplace = document.URL.replace('&a=editar','');
```

ou

```
var urlReplace = document.URL.replace(/&a=editar/g,'');
```

Porém, nenhuma das duas formas funcionaram!!!

Comment: O que te dá `document.URL`? Não vejo porque `var urlReplace = document.URL.replace('&a=editar','');` não funciona, está correto...

Comment: `document.URL´ retorna a URL completa do meu site. E não funciona, conforme apresentei acima.

Comment: E testaste `window.location = urlReplace;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você fizer assim funciona:

```
window.location = document.URL.replace('&a=editar','');
```

Lembrando que a página será recarregada.

Answer (score 2):

Tive um problema semelhante, resolvi da seguinte forma.

Primeiro atribui a url à uma variável

```
url = new URL(window.location.href);
```

Segundo, removi o parâmetro da Variável, no caso do exemplo acima é o a=editar da url `site.com.br?c=cliente&a=editar&id=31228`

```
url.searchParams.delete("a")
```

Por ultimo reescrevi a URL sem o parâmetro

```
window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', url)
```

O código completo ficou assim

```
url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.delete("a")
window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', url)
```

Comment: +1 por sugerir o [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). Recomendo que ajuste o código para usar window.location ao invés de pushState, porque a pergunta não é sobre o history.pushState, é apenas sobre remover parametro e direcionar de verdade.

Answer (score 2):

Em browsers modernos essa operação pode ser feita com o auxilio da interface [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL), *Internet Explorer* ainda deve utilizar o [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams). Veja [Tabela de compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/url) com os browsers.

A interface *URL* representa um objeto que fornece métodos estáticos usados ​​para criar URLs.

Use o constructor [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) para retornar um objeto *URL* definido por uma string.
Esse objeto possui a propriedade [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) que permite o acesso aos [parâmetros de consulta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) que a *URL* possui.

Dois métodos de `URL.searchParams` serão uteis:

- [`URLSearchParams.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/has) que retorna um booleano `true` indicado que aquela URL possui determinado parâmetros de consulta. Caso o contrário retorna `false`.
- [`URLSearchParams.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete) que exclui o parâmetro de pesquisa fornecido.

```js
//Cria uma instância de url a partir dum string.
const url = new URL('http://site.com.br?c=cliente&a=editar&id=31228'); 

console.log(`URL original: ${url}`);     //Imprime a url original.


let params = url.searchParams;           //Obtém os parâmetros de consulta da url. 
//Verifica se o parâmetro a existe...
if (params.has('a')) params.delete('a'); //Se o parâmetro existir o remove.

console.log(`URL modificada: ${url}`);   //Imprime a url modificada
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito mais simples do que escrever algo com regex (não estou dizendo que não funciona, só que é mais simples), apresentando as propriedades básicas úteis ao casos, has e delete e colocando em um exemplo "TESTAVEL" com um unico clique +1 ... vou +1 para o Willian porque ele sugeriu a mesma coisa, apesar de ter adicionado coisas irrelevantes como pushState.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o acompanhei nesse +1 para o Willian.